# What is the correct use of -> operator when working with pointers?

Tags: c, data-structures, pointers, binary-tree

I'm pretty new with C so I have encountered many doubts with pointers.
I've already search a lot about this but there are some things that still are not clear for me, and I also think this will help other beginners:

I'm currently working with something like a binary search tree, more specifically a dictionary. 
In both cases I need a pointer to the left subtree an another one to the right. In the dictionary also a key and a value.

**Lets supose we have a struct node with key,value,left and right(just a summary idea):**
Where left and right are pointers to other node

```
dictionary new_dict = calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
new_dict->key=..;        
new_dict->value=..;      // some values
new_dict->left=..;    
new_dict->right=.. ;
```

I'm doing pretty well so far but in some cases I find myself in a situation like this:

```
dictionary->left->key
```

Or maybe more: ptr->ptr->ptr->ptr (any number of times)

- Does this represent a problem?
- Does this affect the performance?
- Is it a bad practice?
- Should I try avoiding this?

Comment: The answer is "no" to all four of your questions.  Although to be fair, `dictionary->left->key` is OK, but if you're finding yourself saying `ptr->ptr->ptr->ptr` a lot, read [The Law of Demeter is not a Dot Counting Exercise](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx/).

Comment: You are far too early in the learning process to be told rules. Rules are too often applied blindly. I have seen too much absolutely stupid code that came from blind adherence to rules without understanding them.

Comment: Does this affect performance? To check performance, you use a profiler to measure it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm doing pretty well so far but in some cases I find myself in a situation like this `dictionary->left->key` or maybe more: `ptr->ptr->ptr->ptr` (any number of times)
>
> Does this represent a problem?

Yes and No. In itself, it is not a problem if you use the `->` operator multiple times in an expression to reach the value you want to have.

However, the more arrows you need to follow, the harder it becomes to understand where you are in your data structure and what your code is doing. And not understanding your code *is* a problem.

> Does this affect the performance?
>   Is it a bad practice?

No to both of them.

> Should I try avoiding this?

No, but you should try to avoid writing code that is hard to understand.

If you find yourself writing a block of code where you often use `dictionary->left->something`, see if byou can move that block of code into a function of its own where you can pass the pointer `dictionary->left` as an argument. The same function might even be useful to be called with `dictionary->right`.

Comment: +1 just for "avoid writing code that is hard to understand"

Comment: Also: If you’re told to avoid something, don’t replace it with something ten times worse.

Answer (score 3):

You use it to refer to a struct POINTER member. Take this struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
    float z;
};
```

Then you create a variable:

```
struct MyStruct AStruct;
```

You would refer to the members like this:

```
printf("x: %d\n", AStruct.x);
```

But if you have a pointer:

```
struct MyStruct *PointerToAStruct = &AStruct;
```

You would use `->` to reference the members like this:

```
printf("x: %d\n", PointerToAStruct->x);
```

So basically, `PointerToAStruct->x` is just shorthand for `(*PointerToAStruct).x` like how @candied_orange mentioned in a comment.

To answer your other questions, having something like `dictionary->left->key` is just a pointer to a struct with a pointer to another struct with a member. There isn't anything wrong with that.

Comment: There isn’t anything wrong with `a->b->c->d` ... as long as all pointers are valid (e.g. not null). Unfortunately, when there are long chains, people tend to be too optimistic, because when in shortcut mode, writing `if (a&&a->b&&a->b->c) a->b->c->d...;` might appear as a torture ;-)